# Replacing values of an array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

i have a question that is burning my head:

i have an array `$x_axis[]` filled with 357 values

```
$x_axis[0] = '1234'
$x_axis[1] = '2345'
.....
$x_axis[356] = '678'
```

What i need to do is to change the value each 10 keys into '0000'

But my head is absoutely shut down today... can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want the 1st element (index 0), 11th element  (index 10), 21st element (index 20), etc. OR do you want the 10th element (index 9), 20th element (index 19), etc. to be '0000'???

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want every 10th to be turned into 0000, you can do that with a for loop. This can also take into account that the amount of your of values can change.

```
$length = count($x_axis);
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i+=10)
{
  if($i%10==0)
  {
    $x_axis[$i] = '0000';
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

People are really sensitive, so i modified the code to not kill kittens anymore.

Comment: Every answer was great, but for the purpose of what i'm needing, this was the one that fits best.  Thank you all!

Comment: sorry, this is the worse answer compare to the rest

Comment: This one kills one kitten everytime it goes into loop. -1!

Comment: Screw kittens, kittens annoying anyway!

Comment: @ajreal: That's what I said in my previous somment :) Thanks for finding this out!

Answer (score 5):

```
$length = count($x_axis);
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i+=10)
{
  $x_axis[$i] = "0000";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 10; isset($x_axis[$i]); $i += 10) {
  $x_axis[$i] = '0000';
}
```

Job done.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(range(0, count($x_axis), 10) as $i) {
        $x_axis[$i] = '0000';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_walk($x_axis, function(&$v, $k) { if($k % 10 == 0) $v = '0000'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to do this with an array function, but off the top of my head

```
$arrayLen = count($x_axis)
for($index=0; $index<$arrayLen; $index+=10) {
    $x_axis{$index] = '0000';
}
```